# Illustrator: Can compound paths have multiple colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have two paths.

A white envelope icon and a red "No" symbol.

I want to combine the two into a compound path.

My question is, **is there a way to keep the "No" symbol red and the envelope white?**

When combining them into a compound path, they both take on the same color.

[image]

Comment: These are not the compound paths you are looking for, move along...

Answer (score 4):

**No**.

A Compound path is seen as **one object**. Other than a gradient, a single object can not have multiple colors applied to different areas.
<sub>At least not easily without using Appearance Panel tricks and using "block" areas of color, never in specific shapes.</sub>

It sounds as though you want a **Group** (`Object > Group`) and *not* a compound path. A **Group** is a collection of separate objects that are treated as if they should always remain together.